# SwiftUI animating/transitioning an overlay view doesn't work

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
VStack { 
   content()
}
.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
.overlay(
   MyView()
   .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .top), removal: .opacity))
   .animation(.easeInOut)
)
```

For some reason **MyView** isn't animated. Someone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In SwiftUI, you tell your app what you want your UI to look like for a given state. Then if your state changes, SwiftUI does the magic to transition from displaying state 1 to displaying state 2.

In this case, you have told SwiftUI that you want a VStack with a MyView overlaid on top, and that *if* there is an animation, you want it to have such and such a transition and animation style. But because you have only provided a single app state, there are not two states to animate between.

The following code example should illustrate what I assume you are trying to do:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // We have two states - the border rectangle is shown, or not shown
    // @State allows SwiftUI to know to redraw anything that changes when this variable changes
    @State private var showingOverlay = false

    var body: some View {
        // We lay our root view down first, and the border rectangle on top using ZStack
        ZStack {
            // VSTack likes to shrink down as small as it's content allows
            VStack {
                Text("Hello World")
            }
                // .background() is kind of an implicit ZStack, which lets other content
                //    flow around the VStack like it had the Rectangle's dimensions
                .background(
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.gray)
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                )
                // When the VStack appears (when your app launches), set the showingOverlay variable to true
                // Two seconds later, set it back to false
                .onAppear {
                    self.showingOverlay.toggle()
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                        self.showingOverlay.toggle()
                    }
            }

            // We only show this Rectangle if the showingOverlay variable is true
            // Since we are transitioning from not showing, to showing, to not showing, SwiftUI will animate
            if showingOverlay {
                Rectangle()
                    .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 5)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .top), removal: .opacity))
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This could work for me, thank you, but I'm wondering if I can use this overlay property https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/3269703-overlay to achieve the same result.

Comment: @SergiuCoca As far as I can tell, no, you cannot use a custom transition *inside* the `.overlay()` method. Any transition placed there simply does not animate. None of [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/animating-views-and-transitions) or [third-party](https://swiftui-lab.com/advanced-transitions/) [tutorials](https://medium.com/better-programming/fancy-swiftui-making-an-interactive-overlay-control-202e691c04bf) that I've seen use a transition like this, so it's probably not the right way to go about it. Is there a specific reason you want to use `.overlay()`?